# Python else not working correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I'm writing python scripts to count how many times certain strings occur but it seems like the else is not working correctly.

Here is my codes:

```
import os

user_input = "#"
directory = os.listdir(user_input)

searchstring1 = 'type="entity"'

searchstring2 = 'type="field"'

searchstring3 = 'type="other"'

searchstring4 = "type="

count_entity = 0

count_field = 0

count_other = 0

count_none = 0

counttotal = 0

for fname in directory:
    if os.path.isfile(user_input + os.sep + fname):
        f = open(user_input + os.sep + fname, 'r', encoding="utf-8")
        for line in f:
            if "<noun" in line:
                counttotal += 1
                if searchstring1 in line:
                    count_entity += 1
                if searchstring2 in line:
                    count_field += 1
                if searchstring3 in line:
                    count_other += 1
                else:
                    count_none += 1

        f.close()

print("Entity Number" + str(count_entity))
print("Field Number" + str(count_field))
print("Other Number" + str(count_other))
print("None Number" + str(count_none))
```

If it worked correctly, the count_none should equal to total-entity-field-other. But I don't know why it turns out count_none = counttotal so obvious else is not working correctly.

Can anyone tell me why this happened? Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Use `elif` for everything except the first `if`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `else` only applies to the preceding `if` (and any `elif`s attached to it). By doing:

```
            if searchstring1 in line:
                count_entity += 1
            if searchstring2 in line:
                count_field += 1
            if searchstring3 in line:
                count_other += 1
            else:
                count_none += 1
```

you increment `count_none` every time `searchstring3` isn't in `line`, even if `searchstring1` or `searchstring2` was in the line (so `count_other + count_none` will always sum to `count_total`).

To fix, use `elif` instead of `if` for the in between `if` statements, so the `else` case only executes if *none* of the search strings were found:

```
            if searchstring1 in line:
                count_entity += 1
            elif searchstring2 in line:  # Changed to elif
                count_field += 1
            elif searchstring3 in line:  # Changed to elif
                count_other += 1
            else:
                count_none += 1
```

This will prevent you from checking for `searchstring2` and `searchstring3` if `searchstring1` is found (and similarly, if `searchstring2` is found, you won't check for or increment based on `searchstring3`). If you need to search all three, but only increment `count_none` if none of them hit, you'll need to get a little more complicated:

```
            foundany = False
            if searchstring1 in line:
                foundany = True
                count_entity += 1
            if searchstring2 in line:
                foundany = True
                count_field += 1
            if searchstring3 in line:
                foundany = True
                count_other += 1
            if not foundany:
                count_none += 1
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your perfect answer!!